# I installed StoryBook and Eslint. When building Storybook, Easlint sends an error about imports

Tags: eslint, storybook

I installed StoryBook and Eslint. When building Storybook, Eslint sends an error about imports =>
Line 1:9:   ComponentMeta not found in '@storybook/react'   import/named
Line 1:24:  ComponentStory not found in '@storybook/react'  import/named

```
module.exports = {
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
},
"overrides": [
    {
        "files": ['*.stories.@(ts|tsx|js|jsx|mjs|cjs)'],
        "rules": {
            'storybook/hierarchy-separator': 'error',
            'storybook/default-exports': 'off',
            "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "off",
        }
    }
],
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
        "node": {
            "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx",]
        }
    },

},
"extends": ["eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:storybook/recommended",
    "prettier"
],
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint"],
"rules": {
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [2, {
        'extensions': ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
    }],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": ["off"],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "react/no-unescaped-entities": 0,

}
```

};

Comment: I'm not getting errors by extending the plugin, instead of overriding it.

Did you solve the problem?